# Check if at least one checkboxlist is selected in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I have checkboxlist in my windows form application and I would like to check if at least one checkbox is checked. If so rest of my code will execute ,if not error message should be displayed.How can I do that?

Comment: Are you really using WinForms? Or did you just call it that in your title.

Comment: Windows form application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
      if (checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
       {

        //Selected some items
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
foreach(var cb in checkboxlist){
   if(cb is CheckBox && cb.isChecked)
   {
     //Your Custom code here
   }
}
```

Or you can point all of the Checkboxes at the same isChecked event. This is probably a cleaner option than the foreach but it really depends on how you need to put it in.

### Edit

I will leave my answer up for comparison but the two that use CheckedIndices are way better solutions.